# Monitor dims and brightens responding to... sound in the movie

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I got an LG 27" monitor connected to laptop and used as a single monitor and it keeps dimming and brightening back. At first I thought this happened randomly. I checked Windows power settings and set all the brightness values to 100% regardless of mode, but the monitor still kept dimming from time to time (it lasts only for some seconds). Brightness changes didn't respond to mouse or keyboard movements, it just happened arbitrarily, not like dimming after some minutes of inactivity. I checked also monitor settings, and the brightness there is set to 100, and no "brightness adjustment plans" are present there. These adjustments happen all the time and are very conspicuous and rather disturibing than necessary.

I left the problem unsolved for a while, and now I was watching a movie and what drew my attention was that monitor dimmed and brightened back responding to the sound in the movie: when someone is talking, the monitor is bright, and when everyone is quiet, monitor dims. Moreover my monitor is connected through VGA, not HDMI, and sound is being played through the laptop, not monitor, what makes the behavior of my monitor even more peculiar.

What I noticed further is that it happens only when a movie is played full screen (via flash player), so it's hardly a hardware problem.

So as I said, altering power plans and monitor native options didn't bring anything, and I am curious what else could I do to resolve the issue. My laptop is Asus R510 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 720 graphic card, and my monitor is some LG 27 inch screen (27EA53 is the model if it might bring anything).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try a different monitor and VGA cable.

Comment: I have the same problem with an IIYAMA E2607E if I use a DP to HDMI 'cable'.  I since switch to DVDI -> DVI and the problem went away.  Not sure if that can help you, but worth trying other cables/setups. Also try a different monitor on the same setup. If that has the same symptoms then the monitor itself is fine (leaving cable and laptop as suspects).

Answer (score 1):

Locate your function key on monitor to bring up Super Energy Saving. On my LG I have to press it twice to bring that up and then turn it off. This will stop auto dimming while watching movies.. it was driving me crazy too lol